# Jquery UI tabs and radio button as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery tabs and I have specific requirement for a program I am writing. My jquery tabs have the exact same form for both tabs so I want the radio buttons that are for the same name like academic potential to be put into an array. A brief example :

tab one :

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="intAcademicPotential[]" value="' . $v . '" ' . set_radio('intAcademicPotential[]', ' . $v . ') . ' />' . $v . ' ';
```

tab two :

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="intAcademicPotential[]" value="' . $v . '" ' . set_radio('intAcademicPotential[]', ' . $v . ') . ' />' . $v . ' ';
```

The problem that I am having is that when I change into the second tab and choose 1 as the value for the radio and then go to the first tab and on the same name radio button and choose 2 the the other radio buttons value disappears from tab two.

Changing the name of the values works, but I need to have both values inserted into a array.
Any tips would be great.